# Phase Portrait for Matrix with Cosines and Sines.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, classical-mechanics

How would I draw the phase portriat for the following system, and then find the quantities conserved along the flow?

\begin{equation*}
\vec{\dot{x}}=
\begin{bmatrix}-sin(\theta) & cos(\theta)\\-cos(\theta) & -sin(\theta)\end{bmatrix}\vec{x}
\end{equation*}

Firstly I found the eigenvalues to be: $\lambda = -\sin(\theta)+ i\cos(\theta),-\sin(\theta)- i\cos(\theta)$, which would correspond to spirals away/towards the origin depending on the value of $\theta$.

> Here is my first question: how do I draw the phase portrait if it is dependent on $\theta$.

and:

> How do I find what Quantities are conserved?

Answer (score 1):

Considering the system

$$
\dot X + R X = 0
$$

with $X = (x_1,x_2)^{\top}$ and $R = \left(\begin{array}{cc}a & -b\\
b & a\end{array}\right)$ the solution is given as

$$
X = \left(\begin{array}{cc}\cos(bt) & \sin(bt)\\
-\sin(bt) & \cos(bt)\end{array}\right)\left(\begin{array}{c}C_1\\ C_2\end{array}\right)e^{-at}
$$

This represents spirals in the plane $x_1 \times x_2$

Those spirals can be a source $a < 0$ or a sink $a > 0$ or a center $a = 0$

We have also

$$
X^{\top}X = (C_1^2+C_2^2)e^{-2at}
$$

or

$$
||X|| = ||C|| e^{-at}
$$